# Alternate ways to identify polymorphic objects?

Tags: c++, dynamic, polymorphism

I've been searching all through the web and I seem to not find any alternate way of doing comparing if two polymorphic objects are the same type, or if a polymorphic object IS a type. The reason for this is because I am going to implement a Entity System inside of my game that I am currently creating.

I have not found another way of doing this other than with the use macros or a cast (the cast not being a portable method of doing so). Currently this is how I am identifying objects, is there a more efficient or effective way of doing this? (without the use of C++ RTTI)

I pasted it on pastebin, since pasting it here is just too much of a hassle.
http://pastebin.com/2uwrb4y2

And just incase you still do not understand exactly what I'm trying to achieve, I'll try to explain it. An entity in a game is like an object inside of the game (e.g. a player or enemy), it have have components attached to it, these components are data for an entity. A system in the entity system is what brings the data and logic of the game together.

For example, if I wanted to display a model up on the screen it would be similar to this:

```
World world; // Where all entities are contained

// create an entity from the world, and add
// some geometry that is loaded from a file
Entity* e = world.createEntity();
e->add(new GeometryComponent());
e->get<GeometryComponent>()->loadModel("my_model.obj"); // this is what I want to be able to do


world.addSystem(new RenderingSystem());

// game loop
bool isRunning = true;
while(isRunning) 
{
   pollInput();
   // etc...      

   // update the world
   world.update();
}
```

EDIT:
Here's a framework, programmed in Java, that does mainly what I want to be able to do.
http://gamadu.com/artemis/tutorial.html

Comment: Under what circumstances do you have an object, but not know whether it's of a polymorphic type? Offhand, it sounds like a fundamentally flawed design, at least to me.

Comment: It's rare to have to care about the type of an object.  If you're deciding what to do based on an object's class, it almost always means you're not using polymorphism correctly.

Comment: perhaps I wasn't specific enough, all I want is to compare whether the object is a specific type. I'm doing this for an Entity System in a game, and I was trying to figure out ways of recognising objects, so I can access components (attached to an entity) that are of a specific type, to access the data associated with the component.

Comment: An *object* can't really be polymorphic. An object is just what it is. The *type* of the object may be polymorphic, I suppose.

Comment: @miguel.martin: cHao comment still stands. If your design depends on obtaining the type of an object then you (probably) should rethink your design. There are other hints in the question that make me think you should redesign, like for example the emphasis on avoiding RTTI (which is a core part of the language): you cannot have polymorphism without RTTI.

Comment: But, with this design I can split data from the logic behind my game, making my game much more expandable. I have not come across, or thought of another design that does this.

Comment: Any system you implement will wind up being equivalent to RTTI, so why not just use RTTI?

Comment: type_id and dynamic_cast are very slow, especially for a game that can run 60+ frames per second with a lot of game logic code (such as collision detection, etc.) occurring at the same time. It's just a lot of overhead.

Comment: @miguel.martin If you're worried about the overhead of stuff like that then you shouldn't go with an extremely dynamic design. All those calls to `new` and virtual calls have plenty of overhead too.

Comment: There's not as much overhead as type_id and dynamic_cast, and also I'm not going to be calling virtual functions, I just need a way to store them dynamically without knowing their type, so the only thing that's going to be declared as virtual is it's destructor. I would prefer to do it another way, but there's no other way (that I know of)

Comment: I don't think `typeid` is slow. It can be implemented easily in O(1) time. I've read of `dynamic_cast` taking O(log n) time where n is the depth of the class hierarchy.

Comment: I thought typeid was slower for polymorphic types, since it has to look it up at run-time. And I hear many people say not to use it, especially in the game industry.

Comment: Well, all `typeid` does is look up a statically allocated object from a polymorphic object.  The logical way to do this would be to include a pointer in the vtable that points to this object: then `typeid(pointerToPolymorphicObject)` would just be 2 memory accesses.  But there may be other implications I haven't considered.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See `std::is_polymorphic`. I believe boost has it too.

> If T is a polymorphic class (that is, a class that declares or inherits at least one virtual function), provides the member constant value equal true. For any other type, value is false.

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_polymorphic

---

Edit:

Why can't you just do this in your example?

```
Entity* e = world.createEntity();
GemoetryComponent* gc = new GeometryComponent();
gc->loadModel("my_model.obj");
e->add(gc);
```

Create the structure before stripping the type information.

Comment: That's really not what I was asking. I'm trying to see if an object is a specific type. Trying to implement an Entity System design inside of my game, so that if I want to access a component of a specific type.

Comment: I think his answer (although not very clearly stated) is how to identify what's the type of an object. I might be wrong though.

Comment: @miguel.martin I've updated with some code. Perhaps that helps?

Comment: Reply to your edit:
I could do that, but I still want to be able to access components by types, due to the systems relying on it.
Refer to my last link in the original post.

Comment: @miguel.martin If you want to access types at runtime you need runtime type information. If you don't use C++'s official RTTI then you'll implement your own, worse version. It's still RTTI.

Answer (score 0):

If you're determined not to use C++'s built-in RTTI, you can reimplement it yourself by deriving all classes from a base class that contains a virtual method:

```
class Base {
public:
    virtual string getType() = 0;
};
```

Then every derived class needs to overload this method with a version that returns a distinct string:

```
class Foo : public Base {
public:
    string getType() { return "Foo"; }
};
```

You can then simply compare the results of calling `getType()` on each object to determined if they are the same type.  You could use an enumeration instead of a `string` if you know up front all the derived classes that will ever be created.

Comment: That's practically what I'm doing in the code for pastebin, except I think my code might be a bit more efficient when it comes to comparing types.

Comment: That's as good as it gets. You're trying to abuse polymorphism

Answer (score 0):

```
Entity* e = world.createEntity();
e->add(new GeometryComponent());
e->get<GeometryComponent>()->loadModel("my_model.obj"); 
   // this is what I want to be able to do
```

First the simple: there is a base type to all of the components that can be added, or else you would not be able to do `e->add(new GeometryComponent())`. I assume that this particular base has at least one `virtual` function, in which case the trivial solution is to implement `get` as:

```
template <typename T>
T* get() {
   return dynamic_cast<T*>(m_component); // or whatever your member is
}
```

The question says that you don't want to use RTTI, but you fail to provide a reason. The common misundertandings are that RTTI is *slow*, if that is the case, consider profiling to see if that is your case. In most cases the slowness of `dynamic_cast<>` is not important, as `dynamic_cast`s should happen rarely on your program. If `dynamic_cast<>` is a bottleneck, you should refactor so that you don't use it which would be the best solution.

A faster approach, (again, if you have a performance bottleneck here you should redesign, this will make it faster, but the design will still be broken) if you only want to allow to obtain the complete type of the object would be to use a combination of `typeid` to tests the type for equality and `static_cast` to perform the downcast:

```
template <typename T>
T* get() {
   if (typeid(*m_component)==typeid(T))
      return static_cast<T*>(m_component);
   else
      return 0;
}
```

Which is a poor man's version of `dynamic_cast`. It will be faster but it will only let you cast to the *complete* type (i.e. the actual type of the object pointed, not any of it's intermediate bases).

If you are willing to sacrifice all correctness (or there is no RTTI: i.e. no virtual functions) you can do the `static_cast` directly, but if the object is not of that type you will cause undefined behavior.